# To exist vs. to be

Tags: ontology, definitions

All languages I know of have a word for "to be". Of course, this conjugates in english:

[image]

How does being compare to existence, as far as philosophy is concerned? Is there no difference at all?

Comment: It is good to know some rather exotic languages in order to  reflect on this. Most of philosophy comes from a rather specific Greek usage of the verb "to be" and its forms. A most recommendable book is Kahn C, *The Verb  be in Ancient Greek*, recently reissued, and also his *Essays on Being*. E. Benvenistes paper on *Categories de pensee et de language* (1958 and later transl.) is good introduction.

Comment: @sand1 thanks very much. I'll accept if you leave this as an answer.

Comment: @Conifold yes, thanks.